# Which software to light pen text on an image ?

Tags: images, image-processing, image-editor, image-editing

Which software (Windows&Linux) can I use to (yellow) "light pen" text in an image?

Like below:

[image: Yellow Markers]

Comment: Are you talking about highlighting parts of an image _that happens to be text__, i.e. a screenshot or about highlighting text within a running application - they are very different.

Comment: @Steve Barnes: On a screenshot. Though within a running application would also be interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are just looking for simple easy to use software I highly suggest you try using [Lightshot](https://app.prntscr.com/en/download.html). It's a nifty little tool that lets you use a highlighter on the image as well as draw arrows, lines, boxes and write text. Here is a [tutorial](https://youtu.be/dfu_AVqLDQY) for working with Lightshot.

[image]

Windows also has a built-in screenshotting tool called Snipping-tool that is similar to Lightshot.

[image]

If you are wanting to extract the text from the screenshot as well, then you would need a screenshotting tool that also has OCR support. You could check out the OCR Screen Capture demo from LEADTOOLS [here](https://www.leadtools.com/demos/click-once/ocr-screen-capture)

Disclaimer: I am an employee of this prodcuct

Comment: Nice. Feature request to pass on: 1. Adjustable marker size. 2. If I press CTRL while marking, it should restrict movement to stay in a (horizontal) line (from start point + marker height/2), with **a little** wobble (generated by the actual movement or whatever algorithm looks good). Right now, I'm slipping too much over/below the line I want to mark. Otherwise great tool. PS: It lacks a downloadable zip (no-setup). I have no admin rights to install anything on the corporate computer.

Comment: Also,
 add the path to lightshot to the registry (when non-administrator),
 in app paths,
 e.g.
 [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\Lightshot.exe]
@="D:\\Programme\\lightshot\\Lightshot.exe" . That way I can start it when necessary with super+R ;)